# How do I create a simple JSON Jersey 2.x RESTful web service on Glassfish 4?

Tags: json, rest, glassfish, jackson, jersey-2.0

I've spent days trying to figure this out.  All I want to do is create a simple web service to return Lists of POJOs as JSON.  Why is this so difficult?

I'm starting with this in my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my ResourceConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("reservations")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("com.oracle.swr.ws.mavenproject3",  
                 "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base");
    }
}
```

Here is my Resource:

```
@Path("/bookedAssets")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> getJson() {

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("test");
        strings.add("test2");
        return strings;
    }
}
```

When I  try to run it I get:

**Severe:   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.**

I modified my ResourceConfig to try to use JacksonFeature:

```
public ApplicationConfig() {
    super(GenericResource.class, JacksonFeature.class);
}
```

And I get this error message:

**Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.oracle.swr.ws.mavenproject3.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.oracle.swr.ws.mavenproject3.ApplicationConfig threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.ObjectProvider]; Bindings: [QualifierInstance{annotationClass=interface javax.enterprise.inject.Default, values={}, hashCode=633679645}]**

I've tried many different combinations of things in my POM.  No luck.  I've read the Jersey documentation.  No luck.

This guy says the Jersey documentation is crap and to do this instead:  http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Beware-of-JacksonFeature-in-Jersey-td7581633.html.  Tried it.  No luck.

Does anyone have a really simple example of getting GF 4.x, Jersey 2.x, Jackson 2.x working?

Comment: Try putting jackson as `provided` also. Glassfish comes shipped with this module. I think that module is dependent on other modules that may be conflicting in versions.

Comment: @peeskillet I added "provided" and it, unfortunately, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try and get rid of the `jersey-json-media-jackson`, add [this one](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers), and register the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` and see what happens

Comment: +1 for `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` -- base is just the shared base package for all datatypes (json, xml, smile, cbor), and will not help with registration of concrete providers.

Comment: Actually nevermind.  It looks like it was "holding on" to some old jars because when I did a clean build and deploy it, I'm getting the following error: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.lang.String>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Per comment from @peeskillet) 
I replaced this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
packages("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base");
```

with:

```
packages("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't the answer.  I'm now getting the following in the glassfish logs:  MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.lang.String>.

Comment: What makes you think it should be in a provided scope?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [DropWizard](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/) instead of directly using Jersey.
DropWizard integrates things (Jersey, Jackson, logging etc) nicely and setup is a breeze. Alternatively you could consider [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) unless Jersey usage is a strict requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are limited in our 3rd party software usage AND we have a pretty large Java EE stack already in use, so adding to that is probably a non-starter.

Comment: I hear you. Sometimes inertia kills progress. But use of "vanilla" Jersey these days is unfortunately a losing proposition. Good luck still, once you get it figured out it works fine. It's bootstrapping that's usually gnarly.

Comment: An app server integrates those as well. If you don't want this out-of-the-box integration, you can still choose your own dependencies. If you then choose Jersey, just check its one-page doc that will tell you what to mix-and-match (really 3 maven dependencies, quite brain-dead, and it's your choice not to take your server's dependencies in this case). Same would apply for resteasy, for example: stick to your server implementation, or take another. DropWizard/SpringBoot are no different, except they aren't standard Java EE.

Comment: @ymajoros I would argue that whereas RESTeasy, DropWizard and Spring Boot provide 95% of what you need, traditional J2EE App Servers provide 550%, with significantly bigger memory footprint and more complicated deployment. Instead of a single (uber-)jar, there is the whole install, configure app server, then separately build, deploy war, start/stop container etc. etc. Put another way, the only reason to run on App Server that I see is because you have to for legacy reasons. If starting from scratch, there is no benefit to using them.

Comment: @StaxMan they implement standards. Your app runs on any on them (if you code to standards). There is a spec (not for DropWizard et al). The config part etc? You'll always need to configure you db connections, but that's about it (for similar use cases). There is a big difference between big old things (WebSphere) and small efficient, but full Java EE implementations like Wildfly, GF/Payara etc. You're just wrong about the size, those Java EE app servers will be as big/smaller than your typical dependency chain. Install? Just unzip (or even run a single dependency if you want to prove a point).

Comment: @ymajoros "standards" is an empty word with no intrinsic meaning.
As to size, I indeed referred to old skool variants ("traditional"). Good to hear there are smaller variants, although that then becomes question of "why bother"; direction leads to DropWizard/SpringBoot approach, so why not use the real thing. But to each his own. To me, JavaEE approach is akin to EJB become EJB3, undoing damage, instead of dropping dead and letting Hibernate et al take over as is.

Comment: Standards mean multiple people or companies agreed, not just random guys with the power to commit code. In the Java EE world, this means JSRs, specifications, multiple implementations. None of that in Spring or Dropwizard. Standards matter, it means some quality engineering had been done before even starting any implementation. It means you can switch implementations, which I do when occasionally needed. Standards and Java EE is the reason I'm still doing Java. It does bring some quality platform. But we're off topic by now, let's get the discussion somewhere else if you really want to.

Comment: Standards mean different things in different places, and for Java JCP/JSR process is at the point where it hurts more than helps. I have less than zero faith in Java standards at this point, and see very little value in them. Standards for communication protocols, data formats and so on are valuable. For Java stacks, worthless. But yes, we digress, and there's very little common ground to be gained.